# cursor.requery is deprecated что теперь делать?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

После удалении из БД данных надо обновить ListView чтобы отображать изменении. Но Студия говорит что `requery() is deprecated` . Какую функцию можно использовать вместе него? Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7157142) говорят что надо повторно вызвать курсор. Но я не понял как это надо делать.

**UPD:** Скопировал первый код и заново вызвал курсор этим кодом не помогло.

```
cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом. Сначала повторно вызвал курсор тем кодом которым он был создан.

```
cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null);
```

Потом использовал функции `SimpleCursorAdapter` :

```
userAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Работает как надо. Первым делом вызываем курсор снова потом используем вышеперечисленные методы. Всё вместе выглядит так:

```
cursor =  mSqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from "+ DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null);
            userAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

PS1. В решении проблемы помогла вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937839/android-how-to-requery-a-cursor-to-refresh-listview-after-deleting-database-row)

PS2. Если у вас нет `SimpleCursorAdapter` надо его создать чем то похожим на вот это:

```
userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.siyahi_obyekti,
            cursor, headers, new int[]{R.id.textView5, R.id.textView6,R.id.textView7}, 0);
    siyahi.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не поняли главной цели Гугла (Андроида) по изменению политики к курсорам. Идея состоит в том, чтобы вывести процесс загрузки курсора из основного потока, в фоновый, который бы не тормозил работу приложения для пользователя. ДА, Вы воспользовались командой

```
swapCursor(cursor);
```

но это как к японскому автомобилю березовая тяга. Эта команда предназначена для того, чтобы обновить данные в основном потоке на УЖЕ загруженный в фоновом режиме курсор. Изменения работы с курсором - большая тема, и там нельзя отделаться несколькими командами. Советую изучить КурсорЛоудеры или, хотя бы ассинхронные задачи, это первое. А второе - Контент Провайдеры, если нужно обмениваться инфо с другими приложениями. Хотя фанаты лепят их везде.